# Can't load plugin with roslaunch

Tags: ros, gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

My world file (adapted from the [tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=guided_i&tut=guided_i5)) contains a plugin :

```
<model name="my_car">
    <include>
        <uri>model://car</uri>
    </include>
    <plugin name="car_control" filename="car_plugin/build/libcar_plugin.so">
        <velocity>2</velocity>
    </plugin>
</model>
```

### What works

The plugin loads and displays the expected message when I do this :

```
$ export GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH="$CATKIN_WS/src/tas_group_2/car_gazebo/models"
$ export GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH="$CATKIN_WS/src/tas_group_2/car_gazebo/plugins"
$ gazebo worlds/car.world
```

### What doesn't

However I can't get it to launch through roslaunch with :

```
$ roslaunch car_gazebo car.launch
```

and I get te following error :

```
[Err] [Plugin.hh:165] Failed to load plugin car_plugin/build/libcar_plugin.so: car_plugin/build/libcar_plugin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

My files contain :
package.xml (car_gazebo) :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
    <name>car_gazebo</name>
        ...
    <run_depend>gazebo_ros</run_depend>
    <build_depend>gazebo_ros</build_depend>
    <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>

    <export>
        <gazebo_ros gazebo_model_path="${prefix}/models"/>
        <gazebo_ros gazebo_plugin_path="${prefix}/plugins"/>
    </export>
</package>
```

car.launch :

```
<launch>
  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="world_name" value="$(find car_gazebo)/worlds/car.world" />
    <arg name="verbose" value="true" />
  </include>
</launch>
```

### My question

I thought the two methods where equivalent. Because I specified the environment variables in the `<export>` tag.

`<gazebo_ros gazebo_model_path="${prefix}/models"/>` allowed gazebo to find my model, while `<gazebo_ros gazebo_plugin_path="${prefix}/plugins"/>` doesn't help find my plugin. How come?

Any idea how to get the plugin to work with the roslaunch command?

Cheers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15200/can%27t-load-plugin-with-roslaunch/) by [kaldo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3006/kaldo/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-01-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2017-01-12**:
When you say Gazebo displays no error, do you mean you're running it with the `--verbose` flag and no error messages come up? If the plugin is not loaded, you should get an error...

**Comment by [kaldo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3006/kaldo/) on 2017-01-12**:
Thanks for the input! I have modified the launch file to run in verbose mode, and an error came up! I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

As a workaround, I set the `GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH` directly in my launch file, adding an `<env>` tag at the beginning :

```
<launch>
  <!-- Set up env variable so plugin are found -->
  <env name="GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH" value="$(find car_gazebo)/plugins"/>
```

---

Originally posted by [kaldo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3006/kaldo/) with karma: 13 on 2017-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1